# Drawing a slanted partial ellipse defined by center point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've had some problems with drawing a part of an ellipse at a tilt. When the tilt angle, as well as the start and end angles are adjusted, the whole shape moves around. I want to define the ellipse with its center coordinates.

I think I've found a solution, see below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    %
    % Define variables
    \def\eheight{1.5}; % ellipse height
    \def\ewidth{1.25*\eheight}; % ellipse width
    \def\xpos{3}; % x position of center of ellipse
    \def\ypos{2}; % y position of center of ellipse
    \def\sang{50}; % start angle
    \def\eang{160}; % end angle
    \def\rang{60}; % rotation angle
    %
    % Draw partial ellipse
    \draw[thick,rotate=\rang] ([shift=(\sang:{\ewidth} and \eheight), rotate=-\rang]\xpos,\ypos) arc (\sang:\eang:{\ewidth} and \eheight);
    %
    % Draw full ellipse and grid
    \draw[dashed,rotate=\rang] ([shift=(0:{\ewidth} and \eheight), rotate=-\rang]\xpos,\ypos) arc (0:360:{\ewidth} and \eheight);
    \draw[step=1.0] (0,0) grid (5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is this a good solution or can it be improved upon?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is the option `rotate around` which rotates by degrees around a given coordinate. The syntax is `rotate around={`<degrees>`:(`<x>`,`<y>`)}` (or `rotate around={`<degrees>`:(`<phi>`:`<r>`)}` if you are using polar coordinates). You say that you want to slant the ellipsis. Wouldn't then the option `xslant` or `yslant` be more appropriate?

Comment: you can draw an ellipse (at center `(0,0)` by default), and then rotate, and finally shift to the new center. Note that the order of options matters, acting from the right to the left, so it should be `\draw[shift={(3,2)},rotate=60] (3,0) arc(50:160:3 and 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\eheight}{1.5} % ellipse height
\newcommand{\ewidth}{1.25*\eheight} % ellipse width
\newcommand{\xpos}{3} % x position of center of ellipse
\newcommand{\ypos}{2} % y position of center of ellipse
\newcommand{\sang}{50} % start angle
\newcommand{\eang}{160} % end angle
\newcommand{\rang}{60} % rotation angle

\draw (0,0) grid (5,4);
\draw[red, ultra thick] (\xpos,\ypos) ellipse[rotate=\rang, x radius=\ewidth, y radius=\eheight];
\draw[cyan, ultra thick, shift={(\xpos,\ypos)}, rotate=\rang] ({\ewidth*cos(\sang)} , {\eheight*sin(\sang)})  arc[start angle=\sang, end angle=\eang, x radius=\ewidth, y radius=\eheight];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Slanted ellipse and partial ellipse]